# Adding another Website URL to Facebook Login App

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, facebook-apps

I am trying to add another website url to my facebook app in order to use the login functionality not only on one page but on both. Is it possible to do so, since I don't see the option to add a second website url.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add all the website url's you are using to the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" you can find that under settings! or do you mean that you wanna use the same login for a different website because then the only way to do it is making another login functionality.

Comment: Yea, I would like to use the same login using the same app ID and settings but for a different website url. What would be the best practice for that? I use the JS SDK.

Comment: @SunnyK. you can just add the other website to the "App Domains" you find that under "Settings"

Comment: The Domain is already added there but still receiving a message saying that the url cant be loaded. when testing locally on localhost:8081. 

my domain looks like this: x.de
website url is: https://a.x.de

The login functionality works fine for https://a.x.de though or would I need to add the Valid OAuth redirect URI to my js file on the x.de server?

Comment: Did you also already added the url's to the "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" as I told you in my answer above?

Comment: Yes, I did. @tom